# Ruby. Returns an array of random products that have an aggregate number of prices that is equal to or less than max price

Tags: ruby

Note: **The closer the sum of the prices are to max_price, the better**

Initial data:

```
**max_price** = 11

[
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 5
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 6
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    price: 6
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    price: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    price: 3
  },
]
```

For instance, for the first time, we should return

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 5
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 6
  }
]
```

because the sum of prices of these 2 elements is equal to or less than **max_price**.

But for the next time, we should return **other random elements** where their price sum is equal to or less than **max_price**

```
[
  {
    id: 3,
    price: 6
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    price: 1
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    price: 3
  }
]
```

---

*Every time we should return an array with random elements where their sum is equal to or less than **max_price**.*

***How can we do that in ruby?***

Comment: This sounds like a variant of the [Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) to me.

Comment: _"How can we do that in ruby?"_ – Ruby doesn't provide anything out of the box for this specific problem. If your input data is relatively small, you can just brute force all possible combinations.

Comment: I do not understand your question. You wish to return an array of "random products". What do you mean by "random"? The "aggregate number of prices" are to be equal to or less than max price. What do you mean by "aggregate" and why should the *number* of prices be less than the *max price*? You don't need "Ruby" in the title because it is the tag.

Answer (score 0):

As @Spickerman stated in his comment, this looks like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and isn't language sensitive at all.

for a Ruby version, I played around a bit, to see how to get the pseudocode working, and I've come up with this as a possible solution for you:

Initialisation of your records:

```
@prices =
  [
    { id: 1, price: 3 },
    { id: 2, price: 6 },
    { id: 3, price: 6 },
    { id: 4, price: 1 },
    { id: 5, price: 5 }
  ]

# Define value[n, W]
@max_price = 11
@max_items = @prices.size
```

Defining the Ruby subprocedures, based on that Wiki page, one procedure to create the possibilities, one procedure to read the possibilities and return an index:

```
# Define function m so that it represents the maximum value we can get under the condition: use first i items, total weight limit is j
def put_recurse(i, j)
  if i.negative? || j.negative?
    @value[[i, j]] = 0
    return
  end

  put_recurse(i - 1, j) if @value[[i - 1, j]] == -1 # m[i-1, j] has not been calculated, we have to call function m
  return unless @prices.count > i

  if @prices[i][:price] > j # item cannot fit in the bag
    @value[[i, j]] = @value[[i - 1, j]]
  else
    put_recurse(i - 1, j - @prices[i][:price]) if @value[[i - 1, j - @prices[i][:price]]] == -1 # m[i-1,j-w[i]] has not been calculated, we have to call function m
    @value[[i, j]] = [@value[[i - 1, j]], @value[[i - 1, j - @prices[i][:price]]] + @prices[i][:price]].max
  end
end

def get_recurse(i, j)
  return if i.negative?

  if @value[[i, j]] > @value[[i - 1, j]]
    @ret << i
    get_recurse(i - 1, j - @prices[i][:price])
  else
    get_recurse(i - 1, j)
  end
end
```

procedure to run the previously defined procedures in a nice orderly fashion:

```
def knapsack(items, weights)
  # Initialize all value[i, j] = -1
  @value = {}
  @value.default = -1
  @ret = []

  # recurse through results
  put_recurse(items, weights)
  get_recurse(items, weights)
  @prices.values_at(*@ret).sort_by { |x| x[:id] }
end
```

Running the code to get your results:

```
knapsack(@max_items, @max_price)
```